# React Native styles not working for parent view?

Tags: react-native

I'm getting a white background and the parent view is not filling the whole screen.

here's my render function. I'm totally baffled. This usually just works. This is very simple. I just want a view with a background color and some text and a button. The button renders but the formatting for the parent view component isn't working. Feedback is appreciated.

```
    render(){
    return(
        <View style={stylesAM.container}>
            <View style={stylesAM.textContainer}>
                <Text style={stylesAM.title}>You're all signed up!</Text>
                <Text style={stylesAM.body}>Please check your email to verify your account.</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={stylesAM.buttonContainer}>
                <AuthButton type='Back'/>
            </View>
        </View>

    )
}
```

}

```
stylesAM=StyleSheet.create({
containter:{
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor:'#323AB3',
    alignItems:'center',
    paddingTop:44
},
textContainer:{
    paddingLeft:35,
    paddingRight:35,
    alignItems:'center',
    paddingTop:100

},
title:{
    fontFamily:'GlacialIndifference',
    fontSize:20,
    color:'black'
},
body:{
    fontFamily:'GlacialIndifference',
    fontSize:15,
    color:'black'
},
buttonContainer:{
    flex:1,
    paddingBottom:40,
    justifyContent:'flex-end'
}
```

})

Comment: What does  *formatting for the parent view component isn't working* actually mean ? Please update your question with the output screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have typo in your style name :)
double check it again.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo mistake in style 
`containter:{
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor:'#323AB3',
    alignItems:'center',
    paddingTop:44
},`

It should be `container`.